# jQuery ajax post returns nothing

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I'm making the following AJAX call in an attempt to add a new lead to a client's newsletter via AWeber. Even without any POST data you can navigate to `http://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl` and get an HTML error message, yet I've found that the `responseText` is completely blank. Any ideas why that might be?

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {
      meta_web_form_id: '123456',
      meta_split_id: '',
      listname: 'newsletter',
      redirect: '',
      meta_adtracking: 'custom',
      meta_message: '1',
      meta_required: 'name,email',
      meta_tooltip: '',
      name: $('#name').val(),
      email: $('#email').val(),
    },
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data.responseText);
    },
    error: function(data) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(data, ));
    }
  });
```

The error alert yields the following:

```
{"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}
```

**UPDATE**

If I update the `dataType` to `jsonp`, then the 
{readyState:4,status:200,"statusText:"success"}"

Comment: change `complete` to `success` and put an `error` handler in as well.  Also check the console for errors.

Comment: Incidentally, it seems to work fine for me.  I get "Email Address Is Not Valid" every time I post though

Comment: Thanks @Archer. I updated the code to `success` and included an error handler. Unfortunately, the error messages aren't helpful. I wonder why it would work for you and not me...

Comment: what is the response you want from url? `html` or `json`. if json then your url looks like cross origin request so you can use `jsonp`.

Comment: Thanks @Jai. I changed the dataType to jsonp and now I get a 200 message, but now I get a "parseerror".

Comment: @David `http://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl` what are you getting from here? That should produce `json` otherwise nothing will be displayed. If you could share the response when you hit it directly in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into a cross-domain AJAX issue. JSONP can be a workaround for HTTP/GET (provided the server supports it) but not for HTTP/POST -- which is what you are trying to do.

You would have you let your own server execute that request (to www.aweber.com), and hand over the response to you over AJAX.

Comment: Okay, I'll have to re-think the way I'm doing things then. Thanks!